# C# Xml deserialization Element in object property

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm consuming a Web API, and i get an xml result:

```xml
    <tarification cle="XXXX"> 
       <gamme reference="refX">
          <tarif formula="F100">44.84</tarif>
          <tarif formula="F125">47.63</tarif>
          <tarif formula="F150">57.34</tarif>
          <tarif formula="F200">67.95</tarif>
          <option name="indiv-acc">0.5</option>
          <option name="rap-cor">6.06</option>
       </gamme>
    </tarification>
```

I use this model to deserialize :

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "tarification", Namespace="")]
    public class TarifResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "gamme")]
        public Gamme Gamme { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gamme
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="reference")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "tarif")]
        public Formula[] Formulas { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "option")]
        public Option[] Options { get; set; }

    }

    public class Formula
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="formula")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // WRONG ATTRIBUTE.. but witch one ?
        [XmlElement]
        public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Option
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // WRONG ATTRIBUTE.. but witch one ?
        [XmlElement]
        public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

The TarifResponse object is created, all fields are filled, except the two amounts fields. I expect this is because the right xml should be:

```xml
    <amount>5.5</amount>
```

inside tarif or option elements..

Is this format is deserializable ? 
Is there a way to this with attribute ?
Is this even an acceptable xml format ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[XmlText]` attribute will get the inner text of the node.  You might need to use `[XmlText(Type=typeof(decimal))]` to get the number parsed.

```
public class Option
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the attribut i was looking for.